# Copy button for table with row as id and value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to make a copy button. It only gives an error in Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I tried lots of different scripts, but none worked. Everything works except the copy button. I even went to the ICT part of our school. They did not have a solution.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*This is the copy script*

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}

</script>
```

*This is the end of the copy script*

```
<?php
$str1 = "'";
$str2 = '#';
?>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sqlget = "SELECT      FROM redeem";
$result = $link->query($sqlget);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo"<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>Code: </th>




        <th id=" . $row['code']. ">" . $row['code']. "</th>


        <th>Expires: </th><th>". $row['expires']."</th>
        <th><button onclick='copyToClipboard($str2".$row['code'].")'><p id=" . $row['code']. ">...</button></th></tr></table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

*This code is the working version of the copy button.*

```
<center>
<p id="p1">Hello, I'm TEXT 1</p>
<p id="p2">Hi, I'm the 2nd TEXT</p><br/>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy TEXT 1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT 2</button>

<br/><br/><input class="textBox" type="text" id="" placeholder="Dont belive me?..TEST it here..;)" />
</center>
```

Hope you guys/girls can help me out.

Comment: whats the error in console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!!!
IT finally woooorrrrkkssss!!!

It took me a while. But thanks to Blag his part of the code. I found it.

```
<?php $str1 = "&apos;"; ?>
```

This was the sollution.

```
<th><button onclick='copyToClipboard(".$str1. $str2 . $row["code"] .$str1. ")'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
copyToClipboard($str2".$row['code'].")
```

produce : `copyToClipboard(#code)`

It should be :

```
"[...]copyToClipboard(\"$str2".$row['code']."\")[...]"
```

or even better :

```
"onclick='copyToClipboard(" . '"' .$str2 . $row['code']. '"' . ")'"
```

With the output `copyToClipboard("#code")`

Comment: Sorry,
My internet did not work for a short time.
I got the error:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'onclick' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in F:\xampp\htdocs\editor\test.php on line 76

This happened when I did try to use the code you suggested.
But, thank you for help.

Comment: The problem is inside the onclick part